# Client receive different http code from what the server had response

Tags: javascript, java, rest, jersey

I had this weird going on.

I'm using Jersey for API end-point, HTML and javascript front end. When I authenticate user, server will response 303 to tell the client the user is authenticated and to redirect to the said page (based on user group which the user belongs to), which I put it in Location header.

But when my server response with code 303, the client (html with pure javascript in this case) receive code of 200. But if I change the code to something else, let say 401, the client receive it correctly. This happened only if server response with code 303.

Why I return 303? I'm not pretty sure myself, thought it is the right way to do it, I might just return 200, but I try to do it the proper way as much as I know and can. But that is for another time, suggestion are welcome.

And even when I try to receive the Location from header and token from cookies, it return null. As if something happened to the response from server to client. I don't have anything that change response.

Looking at the application log, everything went fine, nothing miss behave.

It was working fine, but suddenly this weird behavior happened. I already clear browser cache, clean build and deploy the app, restart tomcat, and even restart my dev machine, nothing solve it.

I not found anything related with google. My way of code things might not the right way as I'm quite new with REST.

My javascript:

```
                let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                        if(xhr.status === 200) {
                            console.log("Login API return 200");
                            console.log("Token: " + xhr.getResponseHeader("Token"));
                            
                        } else if (xhr.status === 303) {
                            console.log("Status 303 with response text " + xhr.responseText);
                            console.log("Status 303 with redirect header of " + xhr.getResponseHeader("redirect"));
                            // redirect user to the page
                            window.location.href = xhr.getResponseHeader("Location");
                        } else if (xhr.status === 401) {
                            console.log('Unauthorized access to server.');
                            document.getElementById("expired").style.display = "none";
                            document.getElementById("credential").style.display = "block";
                        } else {
                            console.log("Returned status is " + xhr.status);
                            console.log("Response text is " + xhr.responseText);
                        }
                    }
                };
                
                xhr.open('POST', URL + "/api/v1/users/login");
                xhr.setRequestHeader("authorization", authHeader);
                xhr.send();
```

My java:

```
    @POST
    @Path("/login")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response authUser(@Context HttpHeaders httpHeaders,
                             @Context HttpServletRequest request) {
        
        log.debug("Server name : " + request.getServerName());
        String authHeader = httpHeaders.getRequestHeader("authorization").get(0);
        String encodeAuth = authHeader.substring(authHeader.indexOf(' ') + 1);
        String decodeAuth = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodeAuth));
        String username = decodeAuth.substring(0, decodeAuth.indexOf(':'));
        String password = decodeAuth.substring(decodeAuth.indexOf(':') + 1);
        User user = new User(username);
        
        log.debug("Username : " + username);
        log.debug("Password : " + password);
        
        // Check user
        if (!user.login(username,password)) {
            // This is a response for the ajax for unauthorized login
            log.warn("Can not authenticate user, either wrong username or password.");
            // Return Unauthorized response
            return Response
                    .status(401)
                    .entity("Unauthorized")
                    .build();
        }
        
        log.debug("Authentication success. Proceed with token and cookie creation");
        // Create token
        String token = TokenStore.getInstance().putToken(username);
        // Get user's group
        String userGroup = TokenStore.getInstance().getGroup(token);
        
        log.debug("Token created for the user is " + token);
        // Create cookie
        NewCookie cookie = new NewCookie("Token",token,"/app/", request.getServerName(),"User token",1800,false);
        
        /* Create redirect URL. 
         * uriInfo.getBaseUriBuilder() will return http://<host>:<port>/app/api/ which is not 
         * desired in this scenario, the below is to eliminate /api/ from the URI 
         * to get only http://<host>:<port>/app
         */
        
        String uri = uriInfo.getBaseUriBuilder().toString();
        // nthLastIndexOf(2, "/", uri) is a helper method to get the nth occurrence of a character in a string, from the last character.
        int secondLast = nthLastIndexOf(2, "/", uri);
        String base = uri.substring(0,secondLast);
        String redirect = "";
        if(null != userGroup) switch (userGroup) {
            case "groupA":
                redirect = base +  "/pageA";
                break;
            case "groupB":
                redirect = base +  "/pageB";
                break;
            case "groupC":
                redirect = base +  "/pageC";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        
        URI re = null;
        
        log.debug("Created URI for redirect is " + redirect);
        try {
            re = new URI(redirect);
        } catch (URISyntaxException syntax) {
            log.error("Cannot convert string to URI", syntax);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Cannot convert string to URI", e);
        }
        
        log.debug("Return response 303.");
        // Return redirect response
        return Response
                .status(303)
                .entity(token)
                .header("Location", redirect)
                .cookie(cookie)
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: 303 is a redirect status.  When an HTTP client gets a 303, it's supposed to make a second HTTP request, to a different URL.  Are you sure that you're not seeing the status of the second request?

Comment: Yes I'm sure not seeing the status of the second request. Is the redirect happened automatically? As I'm doing right now, I retrieve the code and redirect to the page manually . By manually I mean I use window.location.href to redirect to the desired page.

Comment: Well, I don't know about your particular HTTP client, but I'd be very surprised if you've got one that DOESN'T do the redirect automatically.  You absolutely SHOULDN'T be writing code that detects a 303 and sets `window.location.href`, unless you're developing your own browser.

Comment: I might doing something wrong here because if I don't detect the code and redirect it, the page wont redirect by itself. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Do you use ajax for the authentication ? If so you shouldnt redirect on the server, but send a 200 response with eventually a json payload with the url to redirect to. The browser follows redirects and there is no way to know in js that there was a redirect, you just see the 200 of the redirected page. And it wont redirect the user, it's just your ajax request that got redirected

Comment: @Lk77, yes I'm using ajax. I see, that is how ajax works. But previously when it was working, I could get the 303 code , not seeing the 200 code, and I could redirect it manually, could you explain what was happened back then, so that I could understand more.  In the mean time, taking your advice and Dawood's, I'll change my algorithm.

Comment: Perhaps a 303 with missing Location header i don't know

Comment: Thank you @Lk77, I believe that what was happened. Thank you again and also to Dawood.